# How to force snake_case in all request and response parameters in spectral

Tags: openapi, spectral, jsonpath-plus

I'm trying to use spectral to make all the property names in request and response to match snake_case name convention, but I am not able to get the syntax right. I have the following config file for spectral:

```yaml
extends: ["spectral:oas", "spectral:asyncapi"]
rules:
  snake-case-for-keys:
    description: Keys must use snake_case
    severity: error
    given: $.schemas.*.properties.*
    then:
      field: '@key'
      function: pattern
      functionOptions:
        match: '^[a-z_\/{}]*$'
```

What I want is that if you write the following yaml then it fails because `someProperty` should be written like `some_property`:

```yaml
components:
  schemas:
    SomeSchema:
      type: array
      items:
        type: object
        properties:
          someProperty: # should be 'some_property'
          type: string
```

For now I think checking that on the schemas is enough, but not sure if I should check it also on all the responses and requests too. Any idea how to achieve this behaviour? I suppose I have a wrong `given` clause in my rule.

Answer (score 0):

You should indeed change your *given* clause, so that it resolves to property definitions which happen to be inline OR defined under components/schemas section.

To do this, use the following [jsonpath-plus](https://github.com/JSONPath-Plus/JSONPath) path

```
given: $..properties[*]~
```

This path resolves to any schema property anywhere in the document.

Additionally, you shouldn't need the `field: '@key'` statement as spectral will iterate all the returned "given" values.

So in conclusion, try the following rule definition:

```
rules:
  snake-case-for-keys:
    ...
    given: $..properties[*]~
    then:
      function: pattern
      functionOptions:
        match: '^[a-z_\/{}]*$'
```